# How to implement per-request in-memory "cache" of value in django

Tags: python, django

I'd like to store a value from the database that isn't going to change during a request/response cycle, but gets used hundreds (potentially thousands) of times.

e.g.:

```
#somefile.py

def get_current_foo(request): # this gets called a lot and is currently a bottleneck
  foo = get_foo_from_db(request.blah)
  return foo
```

Currently I use memcached to store the value, but this thing gets called enough that even using memcached to store the value is a bottleneck (I'm profiling it as we speak). Is there a way to "cache" the value in-memory for the current request/response cycle?

( follow up from [Are python "global" (module) variables thread local?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15365519/are-python-global-module-variables-thread-local) )

Comment: Can you store it on the request object itself perhaps?

Comment: I can't think of why not. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Per-request cache in Django?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3151469/per-request-cache-in-django)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is per-request data, store it on the request object itself. :-)

See [Per-request cache in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3151469/per-request-cache-in-django) for some techniques to do so.

Comment: That link seems to address caching the request itself in threadlocals, which solves a different concern (passing the request around everywhere). Since I have the request already, it seems I can just add the attribute to it, and check for it in future calls, simple enough, if i'm understanding correctly.

Comment: @BenRoberts: the second answer stores things directly on the Django request; I wasn't 100% certain that you could simply do `request.my_cache = cachedvalue` and then test for it with `getattr(request, 'my_cache', None)`.

Comment: Ah.  Got it.  I'll try the basic way first and if that doesn't work, I'll go down that route.

Comment: Simply setting the attribute (request.myvalue) and using getattr(request, 'myvalue', None)  seems to be working fine.